# DataGrid inside Grid with VerticalAlignment set to Stretch scroll bars are not showing

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I've a WPF windows application.
I'm loading a DataGrid control into a cell of a Grid. I've set VerticalAlignment property to Stretch and Height to Auto. In design view, it is showing properly.
When I run the application, all the rows are added without scroll bars. As the rows goes beyond the application's size, I'm not able to view the rows that goes beyond the application size. When I set the Height property to some value, scroll bars are showing properly.
Please let me know what I'm missing.

Thanks and Regards
ArunDhaJ